# File Upload error: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect with jersey 2.x and swagger 1.5

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I am trying to create RESUfull web services with swagger documentation. After i googled and found the below mentioned two dependencies are the latest and both works fine.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I have created API for GET and POST request. and I am able to get the responses for both GET and POST.

Now my new requirement is to create file upload POST API. So i fowlloed the stranded coding proacties, 
1) added MultipartFeature in web.xml from glassfish api
     org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
2) my POST API

```
**import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
     import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;**
   @POST
    @Path("/pdfupload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML)
    @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(dataType="file", paramType="formData", name="file")})
    public Response fileUpload(@ApiParam(value="PDF File Upload", required=true) @FormDataParam("file") InputStream pdfInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) {
        String uploadSuccessful = null;
        if (null != pdfInputStream) {
            uploadSuccessful = "API successfully called "+ fileDetails.getFileName();
        }
        return Response.ok(uploadSuccessful).build();
    }
```

I am facing two issue with this API now, 
First, I am not getting choose file button in swagger documentation and I tried different approach to get the button @ApiImplicitParams. 
Secondly, I am getting "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" error response(400), I am not sure what is missing here.

Could you please someone help me this. 
Appreciate your help.